# How to Create an extension?

Tags: extension, civicrm-home, civicrm-entity

I am really finding it difficult in creating an extension in CiviCRM.

I just want to create a section in contacts Called DSearch like , when we click in contacts we get differeent sections like Address , Notes, Communication Preferences etc.

Comment: You are asking about how to create an extension but it may be more useful if you can clearly explain what the outcome is that you want. I don't understand the outcome at this point. Perhaps provide a screenshot of the page as it looks now, and how you want it to look, and provide links to the demo site if the screenshot does not make it clear what the page is.

Answer (score 3):

Not everyone has the skills to create extensions. But here are a couple of links that you might find useful:

https://github.com/totten/civix

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension

Comment: You can always learn the skills :)

Civix is awesome. It is a great tool.

Comment: @Sanjay Jain How to get to the "civix generate:module" ?? I am not able to get into it.

Comment: The Github page has download zip button or you can use git clone https://github.com/totten/civix.git

Comment: @Sanjay Jain I have downloaded, but the issue is how to I make it work to create just an extension. THe documents are really confusing to start with it. Is there any video tutorials ?

Comment: I am one of those people who doesn't know how to create an extension. You might get help at IRC http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#civicrm

Comment: I just want to create a section in contacts Called DSearch like , when we click in contacts we get differeent sections like  Address , Notes, Communication Preferences etc. PLease help